# Vector spaces with infinity

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, category-theory

The real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ can be identified with a one-dimensional real vector space. However in some contexts (e.g. convex analysis) it's useful to consider the reals augmented with positive and negative infinity, $\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$.

It would be elegant and useful if there was a notion of "augmented vector space", meaning a vector space augmented with infinite values somehow, such that a one-dimensional augmented vector space could be identified with $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is not a field (at least with the particular definition that article uses), so we can't simply define a vector space over $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, but perhaps there is some other way to do it. For example, one reasonable approach might be to identify infinite elements with rays and add those to the space.

Does this "augmented vector space" concept exist, and if so, what's it called?

I'm using the category theory tag because the ideal thing would be a category similar to $\mathbf{Vect_\mathbb{R}}$, but where the unit object is $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. If the details have been worked out for something like that it would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure if $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ is a ring, but if it is, the term you want is [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)). There don't seem to be many generalizations of vector spaces, so I don't know of others.

Comment: Wikipedia says it's not a ring. (But that's with the particular axioms that article uses for $\infty$ - it's not completely clear whether it could be made into a ring with different but still reasonable axioms. If I don't get a good answer I might attempt that.)

Comment: Suppose $v_1$ and $v_2$ were two vectors that both had $+\infty$ or both had $-\infty$ in the same coordinate. You couldn't form the linear combination $1v_1 + (-1)v_2$ because $\infty - \infty$ is undefined. This is probably not the only obstacle but a vector space where some linear combinations are *verboten* is going to complicate things.

Comment: @Bungo right, so the possible approaches are (a) give a definition to $\infty + -\infty$ (I've seen this done in other contexts - it generally seems to involve making $+$ non-symmetric), or (b) do all the hard work of dealing with forbidden linear combinations. I've a feeling one or the other can be done, but it'd be much nicer to read about someone else's solution than to attempt one myself.

Comment: I guess a similar issue appears with my ray idea. If $(\infty,0,0)$ means the ray $\{(\lambda,0,0)\mid \lambda\ge 1\}$ then a linear combination $\alpha(\infty,0,0) + \beta(0,\infty,0)$ seems to inevitably mean the set $\{(\lambda,\eta,0)\mid\lambda,\eta\ge 0\}$, so we end up having to include all convex cones as elements of the space as well. This probably isn't what I want, although I will actually have to think about it.

Comment: If $+$ doesn't commute on scalars, it won't commute on vectors either, which raises the question of how bases work.

Comment: It all depends what you want to do exactly. You can certainly make an ad hoc definition, adjoining points at infinity along every (oriented) direction in a real vector space (topologically you would get a ball), and decide that you can't define addition on points at infinity, but all other points behave normally, and multiplying any vector by infinity takes you to the point at infinity in the corresponding oriented direction. Now is that useful? I don't know.

Comment: @CaptainLama the main thing I want to do is think about convex functions in a category theoretical context. Typically convex functions are defined as $f:V\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, where $V$ is a vector space, but I want $V$ and $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ to be objects in the same category, where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is the one-dimensional "augmented vector space". I think that's what I want, but I could be wrong - it's entirely possible the idea doesn't make sense. The question's not intended to be more than "does anything like this exist in the literature?".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you take convex combinations of $\pm\infty$. What definition of convex function are you thinking of? The ones I'm familiar with typically disallow infinite values.

Comment: @jgon I'm going by the definition in Rockarfellar's Convex Analysis, though it seems to be quite common elsewhere, especially in the context of the convex conjugate / Legendre-Fenchel transform - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate for example. I guess you have to include infinity if you want every convex function to have a conjugate.

Comment: (I am slowly starting to realise that what I'm asking for here might not actually be needed for what I'm trying to do. But the question stands anyway - it seems not an unreasonable thing to consider in its own right, and I'd still be interested if there is anything like this in the literature. I suspect though that my ray idea is the only reasonable way to do it. In that case, any non-degenerate convex combination of $\infty$ and $-\infty$ is another constant, $\pm\infty$, which is the convex cone consisting of the entire real line.)

Answer (score 4):

There are ways to get at something similar, but the shortest answer is that there does not seem to be any convenient category of "convex things" such that maps with codomain $\bar{\mathbb R}$ coincide with convex functions in the ordinary sense. The problem is that convex functions aren't closed under composition.

Since they don't compose, I think it's probably best to think of convex functions $X\to \bar{\mathbb R}$ as *objects* of a slice category of convex spaces over $\bar{\mathbb R}$. There is a nice finitarily monadic [category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convex+space) of such spaces, essentially being sets equipped with combinations $tx+(1-t)y$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, whose morphisms are functions that strictly preserve the convex-linear combinations. Now, $\bar{\mathbb R}$ does not live in this category, but this is sensible, since there's no natural way to define convex-linear combinations such as $\frac 12 \infty +\frac 12(-\infty)$. For instance, you can easily prove that there's no such definition which continuously extends the convex combinations from $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I know about convex spaces. Just to be clear, I wasn't trying to make a category where the maps are convex functions (at least not yet), I was just trying to make a nice category for their domains and codomains to live in. But I realised that if you define a convex function as its epigraph (as Rockafellar does) then you don't actually need the extended reals, because you can treat $f(x)=+\infty$ as just notation for "there is no point $(x,y)$ in the epigraph of $f$." At least I think that will work out. It seems more promising than my other approaches.